# How I can pass input value from one file to another file (tkinter)?

Tags: python, user-interface, variables, tkinter

How to I get `textvariable=category_name` in `show_product.py` file and pass to `list_product.py` file without **running the first file in second file**. I tested global variable and `import` that to second file, but first file run into second file.

First file `show_product.py`:

```
category_name_label = Label(show_product, bg='#E0F8C7', width=12, height=1,
                            text=':select category', font=('B Mitra Bold' , 14))
category_name_label.place(x=600 , y=410)
category_name_input = Combobox(show_product, textvariable=category_name,
                               justify=CENTER, font=('B Mitra', 16))
category_name_input.place(x=470, y=411, height=35, width=110)

category_name_input['values'] = [name_category for name_category in all_category]
category_name_input['state'] = 'readonly'
```

Second file `list_product.py`:

```
product_name_input = Entry(list_product, textvariable=product_name,
                           font=('B Mitra Bold', 14), borderwidth=0)
product_name_input.place(x=950, y=340, height=35, width=110)
```

Comment: This question needs a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). Please see [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Always provide a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example").

Comment: "How to pass input value from one Python script file to another Python script file?" Just use a data file (as a kind of global variable accessible to all applications) you write to and then read its content in the another application. This has nothing to do with tkinter, so it is a good idea to remove the tkinter flag.